# upper and lowercase string encryption and decryption, basic cipher c++

Tags: c++, encryption, uppercase, lowercase, caesar-cipher

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<array>
#include<locale>
using namespace std;
class endeMachine
{
public:
    int findIndex(char letter)
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (letter != alphabet[index])
        {
            index++;
    }//end while letter test
    return index;
    }//findIndex
    string subEncrypt(string clear)
    {
        string subString = clear;
        for (int i = 0; i < clear.length(); i++)
        {
            subString[i] = substitution[findIndex(clear[i])];
        }//end for
        return subString;
    }//subEncrypt
    string transEncrypt(string clear)
    {
        string subString = clear;
        for (int i = 0; i < clear.length(); i++)
        {
            subString[i] = alphabet[findIndex(clear[i]) + offset];
        }//end for
        return subString;
    }//transEncrypt
private://---------------------------------------------------------
    array<char, 26> alphabet = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
    array<char, 26> substitution = { 'm','l','k','j','i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a','z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n' };
    int offset = 3;
};//end endoMachine
int main()
{
    endeMachine text;
    string clear_text = { "Hello" };
    cout << text.subEncrypt(clear_text) << endl;
    cout << text.transEncrypt(clear_text) << endl;
    cin >> clear_text;
}//end main
```

So in this program I am trying to eventually get to the point where it can:

- Encrypt a string entered by the end user
- Choose between a substitution or transposition method for the encryption
- Decrypt the string previously encrypted post-entry
- Choose between either one of the encryption methods to do so
- Decrypt the encrypted string without knowing the method of encryption, therefore generating all possible results

My problem is:

When the input string contains an uppercase letter, the whole program shut downs. However if I do something in line 12 like:

```
while (tolower(letter) != alphabet[index])
```

the encryption methods both work, but return the strictly lowercase version of the originally input word, making the input of "Hello" result in:

```
fibby
knoor
```

upon output, rather than:

```
Fibby
Knoor
```

This means that in some way, I need to check for the capitalization of each letter in the word individually, so when it comes time for output, the corresponding letter of the ciphered string can be capitalized before it is output to the screen.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Please sort out the indentation

Comment: First time using this, sorry. I have fixed the formatting. Hopefully now I can receive some help. @EdHeal

Comment: Your alphabet substitution keys (in your code) only seem to consider lower case...

Comment: @Grantly That is the point, I want a method to individually recognize characters of the string, convert them to lowercase letters, encrypt them, then capitalize the corresponding encrypted characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `findIndex` function will fail if an UPPER case char is passed.

The reason is it uses the constant arrays below:

```
array<char, 26> alphabet = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
array<char, 26> substitution = { 'm','l','k','j','i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a','z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n' };
```

So it will not find a match for an UPPER case letter, and your while loop means your index value returned will be out of bounds....That is 1 more than your array size.

You can:

- Check if char is upper case
- convert to lower case
- process via your functions as normal
- if it WAS uppercase, then set your encrypted char to uppercase

...And repeat in reverse for decryption I guess.

There are ugly and elegant ways to check if a char is uppercase...

**Ugly:**

Convert to lower case and compare with original..Are they the same?  If not, Original is upper case.  This is probably more portable across similar languages.  tolower function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/).

**Elegant:**

The char values (for normal English) uppercase characters are between and including 65 and 90.  You could check for the char value in this range

Comment: That's the part I'm getting stuck at. I can't seem to figure out how to flag if it WAS uppercase.

Comment: Edited my answer to assist

Comment: Fair enough. I may just settle for less on this project and make a note in the prompting of the user that this will convert all words input to lowercase before encrypting it. Thus, saving a headache.

Comment: Ah, it will be easy and exciting....This is the function to use to check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/

Comment: I think you can do it simply by adding a pointer parameter to your findIndex function...new param  bool *isUpper;  ... pls forgive C syntax...